# Imitate mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to imitate mouse click on "Name" td after table draws, so it looks like sorting by name is default.

```js
var link = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
var usersData = [];

$(".buttonLoad").click(function () {
  $(".buttonLoad").remove();
  $.getJSON(link, function (data) {
    usersData = data;
    // Table draw
    for(var i = 0; i < usersData.length; i++){
      $("#users").append("<tr><td>" + usersData[i].id + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].name + "</td>"
                         + "<td>" + usersData[i].username + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].email + "</td>"
                         + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.street + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.suite + "</td>"
                         + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.city + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.zipcode + "</td>"
                         + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.geo.lat + "</td>"
                         + "<td>" + usersData[i].phone + "</td>"
                         + "<td>" + usersData[i].website + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].company.name + "</td>"
                         + "<td>" + usersData[i].company.catchPhrase + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].company.bs + "</td></tr>" )
    }
  });
  $("table").removeClass("hide");
  $('th.sort').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
    this.asc = !this.asc;
    if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
  })
  function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
      var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
      return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    }
  }
  function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html() }
});
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
button{
    margin: 3px;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 3px;
}
table th {
    font-weight: bold;
}
table th, table td {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
thead th{
    font: bold italic 100% sans-serif;
    background-color: #f7e1b5;
}
.sort{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="buttonLoad">Load data</button>

<table id="users" border="1" class="hide">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th class="sort" id="defaultSort">Name</th>
      <th class="sort">Username</th>
      <th class="sort">Email</th>
      <th class="sort">Street</th>
      <th>Suite</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Zipcode</th>
      <th>Geo</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Website</th>
      <th class="sort">CompanyName</th>
      <th>CatchPhrase</th>
      <th>bs</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

Things like `.trigger("click")` or `element.click()` don't work at all.

Comment: why not just sort the data you receive via json before generating your table?

Comment: Isnt' it just because the page isn't done loading that .trigger('click') and .click() dosen't work? try something like `setTimeout(function(){$('#defaultSort').click();}, 500);` Oh and like zerohero says, why not just start with it sorted?...

Answer (score 2):

Calls to methods like `click` or `trigger` should be made after your dom elements are ready for the purpose of the scenario that you want to achieve.

if your case, you were trying to sort them **before** the elements are fully loaded into the page, so whatever solution that you will be trying, it will simply not work cause that we are missing something here.

Now, consider this modified version of your `getJson` function:

```
  $.getJSON(link, function(data) {
    usersData = data;
    // Table draw
    for (var i = 0; i < usersData.length; i++) {
      $("#users").append("<tr><td>" + usersData[i].id + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].name + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].username + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].email + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.street + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.suite + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.city + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.zipcode + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].address.geo.lat + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].phone + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].website + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].company.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].company.catchPhrase + "</td>" + "<td>" + usersData[i].company.bs + "</td></tr>")
    }
    // finished loading, now sort by name
    $(".sort.default").click();
  });
```

Don't worry about this `default` class inside the jQuery selector, it's described down below :)

this is my approach to get it working:

1- I've marked the default `th` that you need to initially sort by with an additional class (named default)

2- I've then added a call to simulate the click action **after** the data is loaded (using a selector with the default class into account)

```
// finished loading, now sort by name
        $(".sort.default").click();
```

and here is a link to the complete working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hakeero/rfeh0q7v/1/

Answer (score 2):

**You should create a function `sort(th)` that you can call from anywhere so that you don't need to bother imitating click or hacks like that.**

1.extract the sort statements from `$('th.sort').click()`, and put them in a function defined as follows:

```
function sort(th) {
    var table = $(th).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(th).index()))
    th.asc = !th.asc;
    if (!th.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
}
```

2.sorting by name

```
$.getJSON(link, function (data) {

    ...

    // sorting by name as the default action
    sort($("#defaultSort"));
});
```

3.change `$('th.sort').click()` accordingly.

```
$('th.sort').click(function(){
   sort(this);
})
```

for your convenience, [live demo click here](http://jsfiddle.net/efhszzb8/1/)

Comment: Moving code from one function to another does not change anything.

Comment: @SalmanA I differ with you on that, in the case above giving an anonymous function a name will introduce reusability, it's not just moving code about.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't using click event, you can just move the function away form the .click()

```
function clickHandler(){...}

.click(clickHandler)
```

then you can just call clickHandler() if you want that action